Explicitly excluding invalid overload combinations
I have a function with two parameters that can each take one of two types. Three of the four pairwise combinations are valid, but the fourth is invalid. I'd like to find a way to type hint this scenario that can check these types, but not necessarily have to write code to check for the invalid case every single time I call foo(). Is there a way I can improve the type hints for either foo(), bar(), or both?
In this simplified version of the issue, calling foo() on two objects that are both of type B is the only combination that isn't allowed and would have no meaningful result even if it was.
from typing import Union, overload

class A: pass
class B: pass
class C: pass
class D: pass
class E: pass

@overload
def foo(x: A, y: A) -> C: ...

@overload
def foo(x: A, y: B) -> D: ...

@overload
def foo(x: B, y: A) -> E: ...

def foo(x: Union[A, B], y: Union[A, B]) -> Union[C, D, E]:
    if isinstance(x, B) and isinstance(y, B):
        raise ValueError
    raise NotImplementedError

def bar(x: Union[A, B], y: Union[A, B]):
    return foo(x, y)

For this code, Pyright gives an error "No overloads for foo match the provided arguments" at return foo(x, y).
Edit:
To clarify the use case, foo() is a frequently used function throughout the codebase that returns an instance of C, D, or E, depending on the types of x and y. In my actual code, C, D, and E are implementers of an abstract class (ABC), but I didn't include that in this example for simplicity.
In this example, bar() is meant as one example (out of many) of a place that foo() could be used. The type checker should throw an error if two instances of B are ever passed to foo(). Perhaps then, my question is actually how to type hint x and y, since using Union[A, B] for both leaves open the possibility of x and y being of type B. My overall goal is to avoid needing to explicitly write if not (isinstance(x, B) or (isinstance(y, B)) or similar every single time before foo() is called, but rather have the type checker notice if I ever do accidentally add a call to foo() with two B objects as parameters.

Please [edit] the question to clarify: How will you use foo() and bar()? In what circumstances do you want the type checker(s) to report an error?

@InSync Thanks, edited to attempt to provide more clarity.

Does copying the signature of foo() to bar() (indirect link, playground link too long) work for you? If it does, this is a duplicate of How to annotate the type of arguments forwarded to another function?.

Yes, I think this works, thank you!
